# how to give background colour to textview in android?

Tags: android

How to give background colour to textview in Android?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
textView.setBackgroundResource(resourceId) //from resource

textView.setBackgroundColor(int color) // e.g. Color.RED
```

for custom colors

```
int color = Color.rgb(int red, int green, int blue);
```